# what is the validate method used for in ARef?

Tags: clojure

In clojure's `ARef` implementation, there are three methods

```
void setValidator(IFn vf);

IFn getValidator();

void validate(IFn vf, Object val)
```

what are these methods used for?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A validator function is a one argument function that will be called just before the new value of the ARef (var/ref/agent/atom) is published. If the function returns false or throws an exception, the value of the ARef will not be changed.

The getter corresponds to the core function `get-validator` and the setter to the `set-validator!`. The `validate` is called by clojure code, so you shouldn't need to call it.

For an example see [the clojure docs](http://clojuredocs.org/clojure_core/1.2.0/clojure.core/set-validator!)

Comment: can this validator be anything?

Comment: The validator must be a function of 1 paramater. When the validator function is invokesd, the param will be the new value of the ARef